# How this sentence divided exactly? (ないしょうもない)

Tags: readings, reading-comprehension

[image]

今や売上は中の下でずっと横ばい闘争心もないしょうもないホストになって

The character complaining to one of his sellers that recently he has been a poor seller.
The problem is, how is this sentence divided?

I understand it as far as

> 今や売上は中の下でずっと

However I'm struggling with the rest.

Is 今や売上は中の下でずっと横ばい modifying 闘争心? I feel like the character is omitting something.

My reading would may be  like

> 今や売上は中の下でずっと横ばい

> 闘争心もない

> しょうもないホストになって

are those 3 sentences?

Comment: There's a transcription error too at the end — it is しょうもねえホストになってよ...

Comment: Isn't it just しょうもない?

Comment: No, that's not what I see in your image. (Not that it matters too much, as they mean the same thing)

Comment: Yes I mean, the meaning is the same so I just wrote it in normal JP

Comment: I didn't change the `しょうもない` to match the image, since you know you spelled it differently, but you wrote `ほんと` instead of `ホスト` twice. Just in case it went unnoticed by you.

Answer (score 3):

I'd read 闘争心もないしょうもないホストになって as one sentence though it's not impossible to see 闘争心もない as a single sentence as you think.

闘争心もない modifies しょうもないホスト, as a whole meaning *(became) a hopeless ホスト that lacks the fighting spirit*.

Answer (score 1):

Punctuation marks could be added as follow, without changing meaning:

```
今や、売上は中の下で、ずっと横ばい。闘争心もない。しょうもねえホストになってよ・・・
```

Let's break it down:

I would translate `今や、売上は中の下で、ずっと横ばい。` as `As of now, the sells are in the low medium, and "going sideways".`

`横ばい` in special has the meaning of `values not changing, represented as a line that goes sideways in the sells graph`.

`闘争心もない。` means `There isn't even competitive spirit.`

`しょうもねえホストになってよ・・・` would be translated as `You/He turned out to be a mediocre host... (and I'm disappointed)`

Comment: Not sure it's safe to say punctuation marks could be added without changing meaning; I read this the same way as @sundowner did (one sentence with heavy noun qualification). It is possible that the author intended these as separate sentences and in this case breaking them into separate sentences ends up with basically the same pragmatic meaning, but I think noun qualification is the more natural conclusion here given the lack of sentence-ending punctuation.

Comment: @Mindful True, that interpretation was unnoticed by me. `闘争心もない` could refer to the ホスト